# Tomcat, Httpd : Running both at same time and calling based upon URL.

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, webserver, mod-jk

I am working on Debian X64 where I have tomcat with multiple webapps hosted which works fine.

I have an Apache webserver running which is hosting a `CMS` and which I would like to open when for example `www.domain-cms.com` is called. 
Right now, the Tomcat has 2 webapps which are called again based upon URL like `www.domain-tom1.com` and `www.domain-tom2.com`

Now my question is how to run both together and distinguish based upon URL. I have done the following changes, kindly let me know what am I missing.

Tomcat's server.xml :

```
 <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat">

<Connector port="80" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" compression="force" compressionMinSize="1024" 
               connectionTimeout="20000"  maxPostSize="5242880"
               URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>


<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"  maxPostSize="5242880" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="200" compre$
              compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"  sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="keystorefile" keystorePass="PASSWORD" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>



 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>
        <Host name="domain-first.com" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="tooltank_webapps">
                <Alias>www.domain-first.com</Alias>
                <Context path=""/>
        </Host>

        <Host name="domain-second.com" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true" appBase="aupair_webapps">
                <Alias>www.domain-second.com</Alias>
                <Context path=""/>


    </Host>
    <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
</Engine>
```

apache2.conf :

I have added this in it, but seems wrong as I want to redirect based upon URL, but don't know what to add.

```
<IfModule jk_module>

  JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties 
  JkLogLevel INFO 
  JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories 

// I think below is wrong, I want to redirect based on URL.
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "/error/*" no-jk
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "/blog*"   no-jk

  JkMount    /                    tomcat
  JkMount    /*                   tomcat

</IfModule>
(END)
```

workers.properties file :

```
  worker.list=tomcat
 # Set properties for worker (ajp13) 

 worker.worker.type=ajp13 
 worker.worker.host=127.0.0.1
 worker.worker.port=8010
(END)
```

Now whenever I try to start Apache, I get an error :

```
[....] Restarting web server: apache2(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

How can I connect both Apache server and tomcat and serve CMS and webapps in parallel based upon URL. Kindly let me know. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Port 80 usually used by httpd apache server whereas you are using it for Tomcat as I am seeing in your server.xml `<Connector port="80"`

2) Add virtual host in server.xml to direct different websites in Tomcat for example:

```
<Host name="domain-tom1.com" appBase="/var/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/">
<Context path="" docBase="direcory-in-webapps"/>
<Alias>www.domain-tom1.com</Alias>
</Host>

<Host name="domain-tom2.com" appBase="/var/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/">
<Context path="" docBase="direcory2-in-webapps"/>
<Alias>www.domain-tom2.com</Alias>
</Host>
```

you can write this between `</hots>` and `</Engine>`